# Azure function apps and web sockets

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I can see multiple places that web sockets are not supported in function apps. I just want to create a web socket for some seconds and close it down again. So I do not have a need for a complex socket framework. I was wondering why this settings is present if it is not supported? Has Microsoft started supporting this feature?

[image]

Comment: I think instead of relying upon what others say...you can simply create a POC to verify this. I think it should work if we enable web-socket here in configuration. But again, this may stop working when Serverless Function App goes idle and de-provisioned.

Comment: I am running a POC as we speak. Not that easy to setup, but so little info on the net of this subject so I invested the time. I have done it on an app plan. I will get back with findings. For now it has been running for an hour, scheduled every 5 mins, working each time. Just don't want to run into something, this stopped working as it it not supported Microsoft stuff.  I will get back with findings tomorrow when I have enough data.

Comment: If you are using a Dedicated App Service Plan, then it should work for sure, because that is a machine in the background which is not serverless (always available). But I am doubtful about the Consumption plan.

Comment: Yeah have been testing for 24 hours now works with plan. Ankush can you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Functions are generally hosted in 2 ways:

1. Consumption Plan (Serverless)
2. App Service Plan (Dedicated)

#### Consumption Plan (Serverless)

In this plan, the underlying machine is de-provisioned when the server is idle. So, you may lose your active Web-Socket connections when the machine is idle and de-provisioned.

Also, below is the statement from the Microsoft Azure Function team:

> There are some challenges here because WebSocket is really a stateful protocol (you have a long lived connection between a given client and a given server) while Azure Functions is designed to be stateless. For example, we will often deprovision a Function App from one VM and start it on a different VM (perhaps in a different scale unit) based on capacity constraints. This is safe to do for us today because of our stateless design - but if we did it when there were WebSockets connections to that VM, we'd be terminating those connections. Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/738)

#### App Service Plan (Dedicated)

If you are using a dedicated App Service Plan, then Web Sockets will work for sure, because there is a machine in the background which is not serverless (always available).

Just make sure you have enabled Web Sockets in the configuration (as you have done already).

Check web-socket connection limits for App Service Plans from here -
[App Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)
[image: Web Sockets Limit]